# Haskell: how to do a loop

Tags: haskell

I have to read `n` times and then put it all in a list. I have the following code but it doesn't work. Any Haskell/Functional expert may give me a light?

```
replicateIO n a = do y <- a 
                 if n < 0
                    then return []
                    else do ys <- (replicateIO n-1 a)
                            return [y:ys]
```

Compile error:

```
tres.hs:1:1: error:
    Couldn't match type ‘(->) t0’ with ‘[]’
    Expected type: t -> [[a]]
      Actual type: t -> t0 -> [[a]]
  |
1 | replicateIO n a = if n < 0    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^...
```

Comment: This seems like *imerative code* written in Haskell syntax, although we can write this although it is possible to do this that way, it is usually not a good idea. Here for instance you will call `a` (n+1) times. And although this may look as a detail since you "throw away" the result, since action is an IO monad, this will probably/usually have side-effects.

Comment: Please be more specific than "it doesn't work". Do you get a compilation error? If so, which one? If not, do you get an exception at runtime? If so, which one? Or does the function just not behave as expected? If so, how did you call it; what did you expect to happen and what actually happened? The first problem I see is your indentation, but that might very well be a copy-and-paste issue.

Comment: `replicateIO n-1 a` means `(replicateIO n) - (1 a)`; you want `replicateIO (n-1) a`. Further, you should really start writing the type of `replicateIO` first, otherwise GHC will infer/guess its type and produce confusing error messages. If you do provide the (right) type, the errors will usually make much more sense.

Comment: @chi nice, it compiles now. But now it doesn't let me type(read) anything. It returns [ ] always.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some problems here:

1. you write `[y:ys]` as cons, but a *cons* in Haskell is the `(:) :: a -> [a] -> [a]` operator, so it is `y : ys`, or `(y : ys)` (between brackets). If you write `[y:ys]`, you wrap the result of `(y:ys)` an a new singleton list;
2. you perform `y <- a` *n+1* times, since one of the reasons to use Monads can be to use a *state* (for instance the state of the machine with `IO`), this can have unintended side effects; and
3. you use `(replicateIO n-1 a)` which is interpreted in Haskell as `((replicateIO n)-(1 a))`.

But I think the most important aspect is that you write *imperative programs* in *Haskell syntax*. Haskell is a *functional* programming language. This means a different paradigm. I think it would probably be better to write first some programs that do not work with monads (and `do` notation).

That being said, we can use the above remarks to solve the problem in the question:

```
replicateIO n a = if n < 0
                    then return []
                    else do y <- a
                            ys <- replicateIO (n-1) a
                            return (y:ys)
```

Although this fixes the issues, it is not very elegant and *Haskell-ish* syntax. We can for instance use guards instead of `if`-`then`-`else`:

```
replicateIO n a | n < 0 = return []
                | otherwise = do
                      y <- a
                      ys <- replicateIO (n-1) a
                      return (y:ys)
```

We can make some further improvements (and even omit the `do` notation, but I think it is probably beneficial to first realize that `do` is actually syntactical sugar for some functions).

Comment: thank you so much. Functional Programming is really hard for me 'cause it was really new for me 'till this semester, and it is kinda of hard to think on functions instead of variables. You were really helpfull, thanks!!

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried [`replicateM`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.10.1.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:replicateM)?

> `replicateM n act` performs the action `n` times, gathering the results.